# array to mongoid criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

This query return an `Array` on users variable:

```
users = @users.flat_map {|b| b.followees_by_type('aged') }
```

I need apply this filter to `users`:

```
olds = users.any_of({ :image_filename.ne => nil }, { :yt_video_id.ne => nil}).all_of(:active.ne => false)
```

But I can not apply because is an Array.

**Is possible change to mongoid criteria this array?
Any other solution?**

Note important! I can not modify output class type `b.followees_by_type('aged')`

Comment: Thank you very much! I do not understand what you mean...

Comment: Why do you work on 'users', not on '@users'?

Comment: I will make valid vote if you make a response :D. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, you should use `@users` which is a `Mongoid::Criteria` instead of `users` which is just an `Array`.